# Idea to have a pop-up box of radio boxes on a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search

I am creating a search box form, but I would like to give the user the option of selecting certain categories from a large collection (say 300+).  This would not work very well for a drop down menu, in my opinion.

I was wondering if you could create a pop up box with the background greyed out, like you do with images and have all the categories displayed horizontally as radio boxes and then the user could select one or more of the categories and return to the rest of the form.

I suppose I could use a hidden DIV, but the impact of a popup box would be preferable to me.

Anyone any guidance as to whether this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: yeah ive done something like that, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.I just implemented it to show that it is possible. http://jsfiddle.net/raynesax/u9Ywu/

Comment: Amazing.  You ask, what to you is a complex question and almost immediately a solution is shown.  I think I understand the process, but I will have to study the code to implement it how I would like,  Why do the radio boxes not toggle - once selected, they stay selected ? I  never knew jsfiddle existed - thanks for that info and also your detailed solution.  I have lots of learning to do.

Comment: some areas you've to explore for yourself.I just showed you the right way.And yeah jsfiddle is great.regards

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this easily with [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) dialog functionality.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I will compare with the answer above and decide which way to go.